# Chrome Extension full page or Chrome Packaged App in browser

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I would like to know if there's a way I can create a chrome packaged app or extension in which I can open a fairly complex GUI in the browser (similar to if you visit the settings or extensions pages of chrome, where you get a tab essentially but that's built into the browser). I know you can launch a new window with a packaged app or do a "popup" with the chrome extension. But Essentially I want to be able to launch a new chrome instance with my app inside of it like a chrome:// page. Is this possible?

I know there have been some work arounds mentioned, such as using a chrome extension to open a tab which would then communicate with a background app, but that seems like too much of a hack. Is there anything more elegant to accomplish this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question. Are you trying to open your GUI in a new window without the "chrome" (the tab, address bar, etc), or am I misunderstanding?

Comment: Sorry if I was unclear, I am trying to open my app basically in a new tab as opposed to a new window or a popup like the normal packed app or extension

Answer (score 0):

You can have a temporary page open when your app button is clicked that is an empty page that would open a new tab with the app page you want using the chrome.tabs api

```
chrome.tabs.create({url:'http://www.google.com/'});
```

of course you would replace the url will a fully qualified path to the desired page using

```
chrome.extension.getURL('Relative app path here')
```

Then you could just call

```
history.back();
```

to return to the new tab page.